# ASP.NET web application taking a lot of time to Debug

Tags: asp.net

Actually i have an web application where i have a form which takes data from MYSQL database where i have written an Sp to get the data from DataBase(compares 100.000 records and gives 40,000 of records as output) and bind it to Gridview. At the very first time it takes 15 mins to debug and den for second time(reload) it takes approx.1-2 hours(while i call the same SP in MYSQL DB it takes ~8 mins) Can any one please help me.

Comment: rewrite your application to work with smaller unit of works

Comment: Performance shown are not acceptable; put some of your code -SP expecially- if you want some help to rewrite it

Comment: This is not possible to answer outside of speculation as-is. If you can improve it and add more detail, flag it for moderator review.

Answer (score 1):

You are not going to show 40,000 records at once. You need to implement SP level pagination.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE OrdersByStatus(
    IN orderStatus VARCHAR(25),
    IN start INT, IN size, OUT total INT)
BEGIN
    SELECT count(orderNumber)
    INTO total
    FROM orders
    WHERE status = orderStatus;

    SELECT *
    FROM orders
    WHERE status = orderStatus 
            LIMIT start, (start + size);
END$$
```